# ActionScripting

Tags: flash

I am new to flash and the action scripting. I would like to start my career as a Flash Designer.

Can you please suggest, what should I do before learning Actionscripting OR the easiest way to learn actionscripting ? OR  Should I needs to learn any language before learning actionscripting?

Comment: Why do you need to learn actionscript if you going to be a flash designer?

Comment: because as a designer, I should able to complete all things

Comment: If you want to be a hybrid, usually designers handle the designs and developers handle the code.

Answer (score 2):

My take on the rich internet designer / developer issue: if you want to land a position in a larger firm, where there is a clear division between designers and developers, then pick your poison, and get damn good at it.

If, on the other hand, you are going to be doing freelance work, or are going to be the interaction team of one in a small marketing department (my situation at the moment), you have little choice but pick up both roles. Honestly, I think it is much harder to function effectively in todays expansive and ever-changing climate without being a *fairly strong hybrid*.

To answer your question - "how do I learn actionscript": that is a big question and a deep subject, because it means you need to self-educate object oriented programming. Which is totally possible, but it will take, honestly, months of diligence.

I am a proponent of Zevan Rosser and Rich Shupe's "[Learning ActionScript 3.0](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/), cuz its what I started with. It covers all the essentials really clearly and with real-world examples. Well written and easy to follow. When you've got that under your belt, pick up Colin Mooks "[Essential ActionScript 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946) - its the definitive reference tome and is utterly comprehensive.

And the googles. Lots and lots of googles.

Last point for someone learning AS3: For the love of god, do not program on the timeline.

Comment: +1. Even if you go the designer route, having a decent understanding of Actionscript will make you so much more valuable to the company you work at, and to the developers you work with. Working with a designer who can understand the best way to lay things out to make it easier to code under is a massive time saver. It'll give you the ability to save your company a bunch of money...and that's something someone who's just a good designer can't offer.

Answer (score 0):

A "designer" is generally in charge of the visual aspects (drawing images, creating wireframe diagrams, animating, etc.) while programming is done by developers. Do clarify which path you want to be on.

For designers it is only necessary to know enough ActionScript to add interactive touches to design prototypes, so you could start learning with either ActionScript 2 or 3. Developers you work with will like you better if you use 3, but it'll probably be easier for you to get started with 2.

For developers there's little question that you should dive into ActionScript 3. The best way to learn is by attempting to accomplish something specific (ie. give yourself a project to do) and then looking up information about that. That however assumes you already know a little programming; if you are totally new to programming then look for an intro book to follow along with.

(Incidentally, it took me a little while to get used to these terms at first because I come from a game development background and the game industry uses these terms a little differently.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is admirable that you want to learn ActionScript as a designer. I think everyone who uses Flash should know some level of ActionScript. If you want a complete overview, Colin Moock's books are outstanding:
[http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946)

In addition he also has videos:
http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000289.html

I would advise every person who open up the program Adobe Flash to at least learn how to use the Display List and Events. Those are the two most important parts of ActionScript. That should be a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well good question! I also was a bit skeptical , I am learning Actionscript to :) , I am learning on a video series online. Personally I think the best way to learn a language is from videos as you can visually learn and follow tutorials instead of just reading from a book and not understanding the main concept. Also videos help more as you can follow steps.

Hope this helps!

-Akash

Answer (score 0):

Be clear with all the things other than scripting in flash. Like Animation Designing Movie clips Buttons and there properties. And then start learning scripting. And keep working on linking on buttons and animations those things with scripting. It will be easier to learn after it.